# Multidimensional input : update index when clone existing item

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to change the index of the last item of a multidimensional input when my new item is created ?

Let me explain.

I have a button that is clone an item from my list, into my list. Each item contains several properties (date, category...)

This is an example of what I have when I display my form :

> validation_form[classe][0][matieres][11][ressources][XXXXX][hasBeenRenewed]

What I do is that I clone all my item, but for now, the index XXXX is not updated.

How can I update the XXXX directly when I clone my item ? I thought I could count the number of items, and then change the index, but this would be painful and time consuming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex in `match()` to create array of them then update the one you want and join() back together

```js
const el = document.querySelector('input');

const prefix = el.name.split('[')[0],
      ind = el.name.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);

ind[5]= `[AAA]`;

el.name = `${prefix}${ind.join('')}`

console.log(el)
```

```html
<input name='validation_form[classe][0][matieres][11][ressources][XXXXX][hasBeenRenewed]'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of change, the @charlietfl answer works (had to change to fit into my case)

```
let inputs = new_ressource_clone.find('input');
let new_index = parseInt(count_ressource) + 1;
inputs.each(function() {
    let input = $(this)
    const prefix = input.attr('name').split('[')[0],
        ind = input.attr('name').match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
    ind[5]= '['+new_index+']';
    matiere_zone.attr('data-matiere-count-ressources', new_index);
    let new_name = `${prefix}${ind.join('')}`;
    input.attr('name', new_name);
})
new_ressource_clone.appendTo(liste_zone);
```